# time series with heteroskedasticity in the lagged series

Tags: r, time-series, heteroscedasticity

Dear members,
I am researching time series data with heteroskedasticity.
I have an R code that acts on stock data, call it F(), which returns a time series. The time plot of F() is not problematic and is not heteroskedastic. But when I plot the lagged series of F(), there is high heteroscedasticity in the relationship between lags.

How would you handle these time series?

If there is heteroskedasticity in a time series, you would most probably use the BoxCox transformation to make it homoskedastic. But what if a time series contains heteroskedasticity in the lagged series of THAT time series? If the lagged series has a linear relationship without heteroscedasticity you would most probably use linear models like ARIMA. But what if the relationship between the lagged series is linear with high heteroskedasticity?

I am using R for my research.

Comment: Can you show us a plot of the series?